# How to get a callback from Angular for when the view is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where I update a dropdown list and I need to call a refresh method on this dropdown when the items are updated. The problem is that I don't know how to catch an event for that.

I think the best solution would be to have Angular to provide me with a callback for when the View is rendered. How can I have this? Is this possible?

The code I have is this:

```
    $scope.updateModels = function (id) {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/lookup/models",
            params: { makeId: id },
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.models = response.data;

            //#mySelsect is NOT yet updated with the options here
            $("#mySelsect").selectpicker("refresh");
        }).finally(function () { });
    };
```

I'm using the [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) with this and I need to call the refresh to have the items to reflect the new values.

I've spent all day today trying to fix this without any luck.

As I said, I'm looking for a callback method, that would be perfect! I'm afraid that timeout based wouldn't be a good idea I think...

Answer (score 0):

I would be writing a directive that watches the model and calls your jquery plugin

Comment: do you have an example?